# Assinging a 2 dimensions array to a single dimension array

Tags: c, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array, variable-assignment

I'm trying to write a program that collects the diagonal of a square matrix. First of all a diagonal of a square matrix is the elements when the number of a specific line equals a number of a specific column; it uses a two dimensions array decalred as matrix[size][size](notice I used size twice because a square matrix needs to have the same size for both lines and columns). So, my problem is that I don't know to assign the diagonal to another single dimension array(or maybe I don't know the proper way to do it) without getting the error "[Warning] assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast"

*My piece of code goes like this(Messages are writen in French):*

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int l;
    int i,j;
    printf("Donner la taille du matrice: ");
    scanf("%d",&l);
    //printf("Donner nombre de colones.\n");
    //scanf("%d",&c);

    int matrice[l][l];
    int diagonale[l];

    for(i=0;i<l;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<l;j++)
        {
            printf("Donner matrice[%d]",i);
            scanf("%d",&matrice[i]);
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<l;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<l;j++)
        {
            if(i==j)
            {
                diagonale[i]=matrice[i,j];
            }
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<l;i++)
    {
        printf("Le diagonale du la matrice est %d\n",diagonale[i]);
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: `matrice[i,j]` --> `matrice[i][j]`

Comment: `scanf("%d",&matrice[i])` --> `scanf("%d",&matrice[i][j])`

Comment: you just did it, you said it. `for(int pos=0;pos<max;pos++)matrix_1d[pos]=matrix_2d[pos][pos];`

Comment: Note: Do not use magic numbers. Your code is hard to maintain. If you change the matrix size, you have to edit a plethora of places. `#define MATRIX_SIZE 1` and use the macro instad of the constants.

Comment: Fixed it, worked partially. Not as I expected it to be.

Comment: @Olaf I used magic numbers because I want the user to enter his wished size of the matrix. I could have used malloc using a pointer but I forgot how.

Comment: Do you really know what I mean? Your reply seems not related to my comment. Ynd fi the iser shall input the size, you should use VLAs and a variable with the size. Anyway: Do not use magic numbers.

Comment: @Olaf There is not a single hard-coded number anywhere in that code. You seem to have confused the letter "ell" `l` with the number `1`, and both `matrice` and `diagonale` *are* VLAs.

Comment: @user3386109: Good point! Sorry @OP. However, please (OP) use more speaking variables names. Using the letter `l` (ell) might not be a good idea at all, as you now might have noticed.

Comment: @Olaf I know, it was supposed to be n but if you noticed, I was trying to read lines and columns each with its own variable then I switched to a single variable for avoiding entering different sizes and I kept it as l(ell). I guess I should name it to taille(size in French).

Comment: @Amine: In general, names which are use in a larger block of code should have more "speaking" names. reduce single-char variables to small loops, etc. Your code will be much better readable and you even might find errors yourself. (And maybe it is a good idea to use all-english names at least for syntax-relevant elements. At least, it will help you in international communities like stack overflow. (I'm also ESL, but write my code all-English).

Comment: @Olaf Well, you're certainly right. I had the idea in my mind to change names of variables as well as messages to English so you guys can understand them better, but you know; I'm a lazy person even for smaller things. And the reason I didn't notice my errors is because I was actually writing the program in Algorithimcs and assigning in it goes as [i,j] instead of [i][j]. Was just trying to test in C if the code is executabe.
Will try to take more caution next time; I appreciate the help and the tips.